# I don't understand this result

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, lookup

This code doesn't compile in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d52c144e39191515)

```
#include <iostream>

namespace M {
    class B {
        public:static const int i = 1000;
    };
}

namespace N {
    class Y /*: public M::B*/ {

        class X {
            int a[i];
            static const int i = 1;

        public:
            X() { for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j ) a[j] = 1; }
            static int Get() { return i; }
        };
        public:
        int Get() { return X::Get(); }
    };
}



int main()
{
    N::Y y;
    std::cout << y.Get() << '\n';
}
```

But if I comment out `/*: public M::B*/` it does, printing 1. However, if I place the statement `static const int i = 1;` **before** `int a[i];` it compiles on both versions of the code, printing 1.

Would very much appreciate quotes from the Standard.

Comment: It is fairly obvious that in the commented-out version, it is not allowed to declare `int a[i]`, since `i` has not been defined. If it does compile, the compiler is showing undefined behavior.

Comment: Please rename your question, the title should suggest the actual question.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Feel free to edit it if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code with the commented base class you are trying to use name **i** that was not yet defined

```
   class X {
        int a[i]; // here i is undefined
        static const int i = 1;
```

If you will exchange the two definitions

```
   class X {
        static const int i = 1;
        int a[i];
```

then the code will be compiled successfuly because i used in the array definition was previously defined..

When base class is uncommented then in this definition

```
        int a[i];
```

i is the static data member of class B that is the array is defined as

```
        int a[1000];
```

After that you defined static data member i of class X that hides static data member of base class B of class Y inside class X.